# candlestick plot with the order of high and low achieve time represented?

Tags: equities, charts

candlestick plot does not have information on whether the high price or the low price is achieved first. Is there a commonly accepted way to represent this info on a candlestick plot?

Comment: (If you care about this you should use data at a higher frequency than daily, for example 5 minute bars or even tick by tick data).

Comment: No. I want just a little more detail instead of having to process at a much higher frequency that will dramatically slow down the analysis and possibly introduce more noise than necessary.